# ostream operator << not executing

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ostream

So I have this code written by myself but taken from other example codes...

```
class A{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, A& a);
    // Constructors, destructor, and variables have been declared
    // and initialized and all good.
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, A& a){
    out << " this gets written " << endl; // it doesn't get executed
    return out;
}

int main(){
    A *_a = new A();
    return 0;
}
```

And well, this is just not printing in the console `" this gets written "`

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Your `<<` operator accepts an argument of type `AccountInfo&`, not `A*`, and you're not even showing us the part where you actually try to *use* the operator. You've omitted so much code that was is left is useless for debugging your problem.

Comment: _use_? I thought it was kind of automatic, like when an object gets created. Also the AccountInfo type is a mistake, I will fix it now.

Comment: By "use" I mean, "show us how you're attempting to write your object to a stream". You can't just declare the operator and expect it to do something, you have to actually invoke it. What are you *expecting* the above code to do? The only code you've posted, `A *_a = new A();`, has nothing to do with a `<<` operator or streams. It just makes a new `A` and then exits.

Comment: umm well I have the `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, A& a);` inside the class, I thought that would write it into the console every time a new object was created or something like that.

Comment: No, that's not at all what that does. Google it, `friend` is for something completely different.

Comment: @Yokhen: If you want code do be executed when an object is created, you'll want to put it in a **constructor**, not `operator<<`.  The constructor is executed at object creation time.

Comment: I think it's time for a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)!

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to use the operator via `std::cout << a` or something similar, the problem is you're passing a *pointer* to an object, while the `<<` operator is defined as taking a *reference* to an object. You either need to declare `a` as regular (non-pointer) `A`, or use `std::cout << *a`.

Comment: where should I use `std::cout << *a` so that it's written every time that a new A object is created it's printed?

Comment: Inside the class's constructor. You would write something like `std::cout << *this`.

Comment: Also @meagar, whenever I set `a` as a regular `A` and use `std::cout << *a` I always get the address anyway. The only case when the address isn't printed is when I don't change the type of `a` and use `std::cout << *a`

Comment: @Yokhen : If you instantiate a regular `A` vs. an `A*`, `std::cout << *a` wouldn't compile; the correct syntax would be `std::cout << a`.